# Exporting as CSV in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I'm having some difficulty exporting a set of data in PowerShell.  The data comes from an API query and is acquired using this command:

```
PS [path]> $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Get -Certificate $cert
```

So far, so good.  I can write out the contents of $response, represented here by fake data:

```
PS [path]> Write-Output $response
field1,field2,field3
"dataf1r1","dataf2r1","dataf3r1"
"dataf1r2","dataf2r2","dataf3r2"
```

I then try to write this response object to a CSV file in either of 2 ways:

```
PS [path]> $response | Export-CSV -Path objects_export.csv
```

or...

```
PS [path]> Export-Csv -InputObject $response -Path csv_test.csv
```

The file I get opens in Excel, but does not contain the expected data.  Instead of my nice CSV data, I get:

```
#TYPE System.String
Length
25461
```

So, 2 things:

1. What is that output?  That makes no sense to me.
2. Why aren't my happy little rows being written to the CSV?

Comment: you have a single multiline string OR an array of single line strings. that is not an array of structured objects. ///// you may be able to use `ConvertFrom-CSV` to make an array of objects that can be exported properly.

Comment: It looks like those rows are just strings. Try $response | convertfrom-Csv | export-CSV testcsv.CSV -NoType

Comment: Thank you.  That works very well.  So I take from this that PowerShell likes to "understand"  what it's working with-- just telling it to dumbly write out to a file, like I would do in bash, is not really a thing?  If it seems I've been using this for less than an hour, that's because I've been using it for less than an hour. :-)

Comment: @Andrew the key difference is that PS works with objects.

Comment: Thank you all.  This is working well.